# upload file with python script in plone

Tags: python, plone, zope

I am using plone to build my site.
In one page template, I have the `<input type="file" name="file">`  and this form: `<form method="post" action="addintoDb" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

The addintoDb is a python script that save my information into db:`context.addParam(name=request.name, path=request['file'])`. 
in my db i have name and in the path: `<ZPublisher.HTTPRequest.FileUpload instance at 0x081F98C8>` but i want to have the put where the file was uploaded (like c:...)

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: You have to add more information. Which kind of technologies for the form are you using, what is the context of this form, does every body even not logged in user can use it ... You want help , so give enough information.

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the file on the filesystem, but in the Zope object database. You'd have to use python code (not a python script) to open a filepath with the `open` built-in function to save the data to.